# Maven: Building another project from current pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

My project structure is simply:
P1(pom.xml)

P2(pom.xml)

I want to build P2 first and include it's jar as dependency to P1, and build P1 to get a war. 
Please Help!

Comment: Create a multi module build with a parent and put those two as modules and defined the appropriate dependencies between each other. Recommed to read http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: i don't want to change my project structure.

Comment: Your project P1 must have a _dependency_ to your project P2. Any problems with that?

Comment: Can you show the folder structure of your project? Are you using a version contorl?

Comment: @Forkmohit do those two different projects reside each in it's own directory or is it the same directory with two POM files in it?

Comment: 1. Yes I got P2 inducted as dependency in P1's pom. 
2. Yes using git
3. These are independent projects, with each having its pom.